# Android DbHelper конструктор

Tags: android, sqlite

Добрый день.

Я хочу в Main_Activity создать объект класса "A" и обратится к его методу в котором работаю с методом объекта "DbHelper". Но я не могу создать в объекте "А" объект "DbHelper" т.к. Конструктор "DbHelper" требует указать Context. Но "А" у меня не наследуется не от Activity ни от Context.

Вопрос, что мне передать в конструктор DbHelper?

Грубый набросок кода для понимания:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    new A.methodA();
}

public class A{
   void methodA(){
        new DbHelper().methodFromDbHelper();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Собственно передай ему Context

```
public class A{
private Context _context;
public A(Context context) 
{
    _context = context;
}
void methodA(){
    new DbHelper(_context).methodFromDbHelper();
}
```

Код вызова в активити, если вызывается не в активити, передавать контекст в конструкторах всей цепочки классов:

```
A a = new A(this);
```

Comment: Спасибо. Выручили.